# sonarqube in c# shows no technical debt nor Issues

Tags: .net, sonarqube

Used sonarqube 5.1.2 with sonarrunner 2.4 jdk 32 bit 1.8 version in  XP (sp3),when analyzing any c# project my execution is successful but no results in tech debt and Issues,only I could see LOC,duplication and lines,block,what is the reason behind it?what must be added to get the details in dashboard.Is anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to SonarQube 5.2, make sure your SQL Server collation is case-sensitive and accent-sensitive, and use the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild to run the analysis of your C# projects. The sonar-runner is no longer supported for the analysis of C# projects.

Comment: I Am using H2 database(default) so no SQL,now I cant see only tech debt+Issues report,but other like LOC,duplication,can be seen,now as you told me SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild which version to be used so that i can get the full(tech debt,Issues) reports?Any other thing required for compatibility purpose?Kindly suggest

Comment: Use the latest SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild version 1.0.2, together with the SonarQube C# Plugin version 4.3.

Comment: If i use this in vs2010 environment I will get "%1 is not the 32-bit application" tried with that.Can I have your number please?

Comment: @Rakshithshetty If you have purchased SonarSource commercial support, please create a ticket through Service Desk.

Comment: The SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild requires MSBuild 12 or 14 (i.e. VS2013 or VS2015) and the .NET Framework version 4.5.2 at least.

Comment: If you cant give  your number its fine but kindly tell me what must I do to get technical debt and issues in java.second question for .net analysis in h2 database with xp(sp3) vs2010,sonarqube 5.1.2,runner 2.4,jdk 32 bit(1.8 version),installed gallio,fxcop 1.36,stylecop.what should I do?I cant change XP envt its VDI so..

Comment: I highly recommend that you do things right and follow the steps described in this complete end-to-end guide to SonarQube for .NET Users: http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/sq-setup-guide-for-dotnet-users.html - I'm not going to help you further with your current setup: The sonar-runner isn't supported to analyze C# projects.